# Columns not going to next line with display:flex?

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to css/html and have run in to a problem. I'm trying to use the "@media" that listens to the browser size. I've made 3 columns that should change based on the browser size. I can tell by looking at the chrome-developer tool that the "@media" works, but I need the columns to the next line whenever they're filling up over 100% - this doesn't happen though.

I suspect that it has something to do with "display: flex" but I could be very wrong. Can anyone help me out here? (I will post my css and html down under)

```css
/********** Base styles **********/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.row > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #A52A2A;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.titel {
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top:  0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: skyblue;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  width: 100px;

}

.menutext {
  font-size: 70%;
  padding-top: 50px;
}



/* Simple Responsive Framework. */
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}


/********** Large devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/********** Medium devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/********** Medium devices only **********/
@media (max-width:  767px) {
  .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css-solution.css">
<title>Responsive Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Responsive Layout</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div  class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><div class = "titelbox"><p class = "titel">Chicken</p></div><p class = "menutext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. </p> </div>

  <div  class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><div class = "titelbox"><p class = "titel">Beef</p></div><p class = "menutext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. </p></div>
  
  <div  class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12"><div class = "titelbox"><p class = "titel">Fish</p></div><p class = "menutext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. </p></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```css
/********** Base styles **********/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.row > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #A52A2A;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.titel {
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top:  0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: skyblue;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  width: 100px;

}

.menutext {
  font-size: 70%;
  padding-top: 50px;
}



/* Simple Responsive Framework. */
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}


/********** Large devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/********** Medium devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/********** Medium devices only **********/
@media (max-width:  767px) {
  .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .row {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css-solution.css">
<title>Responsive Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Responsive Layout</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div  class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><div class = "titelbox"><p class = "titel">Chicken</p></div><p class = "menutext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. </p> </div>

  <div  class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><div class = "titelbox"><p class = "titel">Beef</p></div><p class = "menutext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. </p></div>
  
  <div  class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12"><div class = "titelbox"><p class = "titel">Fish</p></div><p class = "menutext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. </p></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this doesn't work sadly. That creates an issue where they get put onto next line whenever they're filling up 100% but because theres a small margin, it thinks its over 100%. That's why I use display: flex - maybe you got any idea as what to use instead of flex?

Answer (score 0):

Try below style under browser size where exactly you want to show columns as separate lines.

```
flex-direction: column
```

Comment: Not sure where to put it based on your description, sorry.

Comment: Underclass ".row" for a particular size